# The Alchemist's Path unlocks the task list of each Chapter by completing the previous, but what happens if you finish a chapter early?

Tags: potion-craft

Chapter 2's requirements don't need everything in Chapter 1 to be completed, since the 4 basic potions, Poison, Healing, Fire, and Frost, aren't needed to do anything in Chapter 2, so it's possible to all of Chapter 2's tasks before finishing Chapter 1, and since they count even when out of order, is there anything special about completing Chapter 2 or any other chapter, without having completed the one before it?

Chapter 2 requirements:

> Pour water from the ladle to move the potion towards the center of the map
> Create a potion with effect of tier 2 or higher
> Create a potion with 2 different effects
> Save a new recipe
> Brew a potion from the Recipe Book
> Haggle for a better deal
> Reach a popularity level of 4
> Collect small experience on the Alchemy Map (2 book icon)
> Create Potion of Explosion
> Create Potion of Wild Growth
> Create Potion of Strength
> Create Potion of Dexterity
>  Create Potion of Swiftness